# DropzoneJs fallback for IE9 not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, dropzone.js

When I first installed DropzoneJS (www.dropzonejs.com) a while back, I included [dropzoneDirectiveModule wrapper](https://gist.github.com/compact/8118670) because it wasn't working properly with Angular (1.3.7). It worked great.

Now, I need to make DropzoneJS work with IE9. It has a fallback class that adds a `<form>` tag if the browser is not supported. It appears on the DOM as follows:

```
    <span class="dz-browser-not-supported" id="dropzone9" dropzone="dropzoneConfig">
        <ng-form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:0000/api/endPoint">
            <div class="dz-fallback">                
                <p>Please use the fallback form below to upload your files like in the olden days.</p>
                <input name="myfiles[]" type="file"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload!">
            </div>
        </ng-form>
    </span>
```

The problem is that the "Browser" button that appears inside the dropzone area does not  work. Nothing happens when you click on it.

Because I used the dropzoneDirectiveModule wrapper I tested with that attribute inside the `.dz-fallback`, which made the basic "Browser" button appear, but still the document window doesn't open.

I changed the `<form>` in DropzoneJS to `<ng-form>` because it is nested inside a larger `<form>`, but no results.

If I create an input form outside of DropzoneJS, then the document window appears normally, but I'm not able to submit the files with the data as needed by my ASP.NET 4.5 Controller. It just doesn't hit the endpoint.

PS: I tried working with [jQueryFileUpload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), but could not get it to work. (It also bugged me to include this substantial library into my app for IE9 support only.)

I need to support file uploads in IE9, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you better convert drozponejs as directive of angularJs, otherwise neither of them will  work properly.

Comment: @BowenLi do you have an example of how that can be done?

Comment: Hi man , please take a look at https://gist.github.com/compact/8118670

Comment: you create a demo case, and I help to debug, I could do the whole work for you unless you want to learn.

Comment: @BowenLi hey, I put this on the back burner to work on another ticket. I've already wrapped the dropzone in a directive,which made it work  with Angular. The issue that I have is that dropzone has a nice `.fallback` class that puts the regular html `input` element in the DOM, but that `input` is not working. I can see it in the browser's inspector element, and it has the type and name attributes, but if you click on it, nothing happens.  I created a [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/oFWvSMzKesWdwAKQjnM6?p=preview) plunkr here, but it's not displaying the proper dz. Thanks for any help.